# Counting user responses

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm having a bit of trouble with some of my code. I've only been using Visual Basic for about 1 month and a half for college work, and for the most part it's been going well, however I've come to a brick wall and I'd like some help or constructive criticism.

I was given the task of:

> A small program to demonstrate the use of objects, event handlers and object properties with selection using ‘If… Then…’ or ‘Case’ structures. Write a program that asks five questions to which the answer must be ‘Yes’ or ‘No’. The program must then add up the number of Yes answers and the number of No answers. If the number of Yes answers exceeds the number of No answers, display a message saying ‘Optimist’. Alternatively display ‘Pessimist’. (You can decide on the questions)

So, I need to check how many "Yes" and "No" answers I've gotten, my code so far is:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Select Case MsgBox("Does your outlook affect your motivation?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    Select Case MsgBox("Do you have trust and faith in people?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    Select Case MsgBox("Do you expect the best?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    Select Case MsgBox("Do good things happen to you?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    Select Case MsgBox("Are you optimistic about your future?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    If MsgBoxResult.Yes > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are optimistic.")

    ElseIf MsgBoxResult.Yes < 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are pessimistic.")

    End If
End Sub End Class
```

Considering I've only been coding for a short period of time, I only need really simple fixes or anything that would go towards being more helpful.

My issue is that no matter how many "No" answers I input, I always get back "You are optimistic". If it's not clear what I'm asking help for, please leave a comment, thank-you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot this part "The program must then add up the number of Yes answers and the number of No answers.".

You need to create a variable that counts the number of yes.

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Dim yesCount As Integer = 0

    Select Case MsgBox("Does your outlook affect your motivation?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            yesCount += 1
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select

    Select Case MsgBox("Do you have trust and faith in people?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            yesCount += 1
        Case MsgBoxResult.No

    End Select
```

And then else that variable to should the result. You should use `Else` in your case, in your code you could have a problem if the number of yes was equal to the number of no (neutral?).

```
If yesCount > 3 Then
    MessageBox.Show("You are optimistic.")

Else
    MessageBox.Show("You are pessimistic.")

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of [MsgBoxResult.Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) is 6. It is a constant - it will never change - and so (ironically) you will always end up inside the "You are optimistic" block.

You need to declare a variable inside your function which you [increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx) each time the user clicks Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I see what I needed to do with the constant but figured out a different way. I'll remember this for the future. Thanks, Stephen.